# Using JSoup to get data-code value of a table

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

How would I be able to use JSoup to get the `data-code` value from a table row?

Here is what I have tried but it just prints nothing:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com").get();
Elements dataCodes = doc.select("table[class=team-list]");

for (Element dataCode : dataCodes)
{
    System.out.println(dataCode.attr("data-code"));
}
```

The HTML code looks like this:

```
<body>
<div id-=""main">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="table" class="scores-table">
            <table class ="team-list">
                <tbody>

                <tr data-code="1" class="data odd"></tr>
                <tr data-code="2" class="data even"></tr>
                <tr data-code="3" class="data odd"></tr>
                <tr data-code="1" class="data even"></tr>       

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want it to print out the data-code value on each row of the table (which is the team number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector should go down to `tr` elements:

```
Elements dataCodes = doc.select("table.team-list tr");
```

---

According to the comments, this still results into an empty list - in this case, the table is probably dynamically generated with the help of javascript logic or a separate AJAX request.

In this case, one of the possible approaches would be to have a real browser handle that dynamic javascript, AJAX part. Try [`selenium` browser automation framework](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted):

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.example.com");

List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table.team-list tr"));

for(WebElement element: elements)
{
    System.out.println(element.getAttribute('data-code'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ive tried this but it didnt work :(. it seems like it cant select the table because print the whole "team-list" table there is no output

Comment: @user1281921 it's either there is no `table` in the HTML JSoup get at all, or see the updated selector - check it out. Thanks.

Comment: I think the table is an dynamically generated code. What libraries will i need to get the HTML5 code

Comment: @user1281921 okay, updated the answer with an alternative option. Hope that helps.