# Using Selenium in Java to get table contents

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

This is a continuation from my other post

[Using JSoup to get data-code value of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28622487/using-jsoup-to-get-data-code-value-of-a-table)

I am trying to get the text inside the `<span>` tags on the table using the `cssSelector()` method in Selenium webdriver

```
<table class ="team-list">
          <tr data-code="1">
              <td>
              <span>
                 Get This Text
              </span>
              </td>     
          </tr>
  </table>
```

I have tried the following code, but this will print out the text in all cells for each row, but i *only* need to get the one inside the `<span>` tags

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.example.com");

List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table.team-list td"));

for(WebElement element: elements)
{
    System.out.println(element.getText());
}
```

Comment: use `.team-list td span` ... u r providing td so it will give text of all tds including those which don't have span also.

Comment: This worked for me `List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table.team-list td > td:nth-of-type(2)"));`

Answer (score 1):

if you know the text you are looking for you can the following:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.example.com");

List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table.team-list td"));

for(WebElement element: elements)
{
    if(element.getText().equals("Get This Text"))
       System.out.println(element.getText());
}
```

That's might be o(n) but if you are not care about performance that could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your selector to this:

```
By.cssSelector("table.team-list span")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.example.com");
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table.team-list td"));

    for(WebElement element: elements)
    {
        try{
           System.out.println(element.findElement(By.tagName("span")).getText());
         }(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException nsee){
         }
    }
```